# subclassing NSDictionary like so: @implementation NSDictionary (weather)

Tags: ios, objective-c, subclass

I am looking at the [Ray Wenderlich AFNetworking tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial), and I have come across a way of subclassing NSDictionary that I have not seen before:

first:

```
@implementation NSDictionary (weather)
```

then in another file:

```
@implementation NSDictionary (weather_package)
```

This seems to just "work" in another file where it's included. What's most puzzling is that the NSDictionary defined in a class that uses these seems to match the "weather_package" version and within that container the "weather" version.

Can someone point me to the name of what's going on here? I am not entirely clear on how this works from reviewing the code, particularly how the compiler decides what to apply where since no explicit reference is made to these files apart from including them in the header.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not subclassing. This is extending the class using categories. This is used to bring new functionality into existing classes without subclassing them.

A category can be declared for any class, even if you don’t have the original implementation source code (such as for standard Cocoa or Cocoa Touch classes). Any methods that you declare in a category will be available to all instances of the original class, as well as any subclasses of the original class. At runtime, there’s no difference between a method added by a category and one that is implemented by the original class.

A category can be defined like

```
@interface ClassName (CategoryName)

@end

@implementation ClassName (CategoryName)

@end
```

For more information read https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1

Answer (score 1):

It's not subclassing, it's more extending existing implementation with new methods, so called categories:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html